# How can I get the product identifier from a restored transaction?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have managed to restore in-app transactions and get the transaction identifier from the original transaction, but how do I identify the product which were bought in the transaction?
Is it possible to get the product identifier for a previously purchased in-app product?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

if you mean you want to check the purchased items that already user buy it .. yes you can do like this

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
} //You Call This Function

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution to determine the productIdentifier (i.e. `transaction.payment.productIdentifier`) associated with the SKPaymentTransaction currently being processed in the queue. Thank you

Comment: In your example you get ids for all transactions in `SKPaymentQueue` but the question was about restored transactions only. Downvoted

Answer (score 7):

SWIFT VERSION:

Once you get the delegate

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    var productIds = [String]()
    for transcation in queue.transactions{
        if let productID = transcation.payment?.productIdentifier{
        productIds.append(productID)
        }
    }
```